# Why this code does not do what I mean?

Tags: regex, perl, hash

```
$w = 'self-powering';
%h = (self => 'self',
      power => 'pauә',
      );
if ($w =~ /(\w+)-(\w+)ing$/ && $1~~%h && $2~~%h && $h{$2}=~/ә$/) {
    $p = $h{$1}.$h{$2}.'riŋ';
      print "$w:"," [","$p","] "; 
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
self-powering: selfpauәriŋ
```

But what I get is:

```
self-powering: [riŋ]
```

My guess is something's wrong with the code

```
$h{$2}=~/ә$/
```

It seems that when I use

```
$h{$2}!~/ә$/
```

Perl will do what I mean but why I can't get "self-powering: selfpauәriŋ"? 
What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks as always for any comments/suggestions/pointers :)

Comment: I rarely get any code to do what I mean. *Sigh*.

Comment: What character encoding do you use? UTF-8? Have you read http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html ?

Comment: @Boldewyn, thanks for leaving the comment. But this problem has little to do with the UTF-8 encoding. The script is saved as UTF-8 format and can output the contents as expected without any in-script  encoding handling on my Windows box.

Comment: OK, that's good. Just wanted to mention the pitfall for most people starting to put non-ASCII characters in their Perl files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run

```
 $h{$2}!~/ә$/
```

In your if statement the contents of $1 and $2 are changed to be empty, because no groupings were matched (there were none). If you do it like this:

```
if ($w =~ /(\w+)-(\w+)ing$/){
    my $m1 = $1;
    my $m2 = $2;
    if($m2~~%h && $m2~~%h && $h{$m2}=~/ә$/) {
        $p = $h{$m1}.$h{$m2}.'riŋ';
        print "$w:"," [","$p","] "; 
    }
}
```

I expect you will get what you want.

Comment: @Sorpigal, so the code suddenly has to get complicated :( But, thanks, thanks, thanks alot, "the contents of $1 and $2 are changed to be empty", this is the crux of the problem :) I've been stumped there for quite a while. Now I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running with `use warnings` enabled? That would tell you that `$1` and `$2` are not what you expect. Your second regex, not the first, determines the values of those variables once you enter the `if` block. To illustrate with a simpler example:

```
print $1, "\n"
    if  'foo' =~ /(\w+)/
    and 'bar' =~ /(\w+)/;
```

Comment: @FM, the code is a simplified version of a toy program I coded that has about 300 lines. I had got a workaround for the problem I mentioned. Well I've just checked the code, no, I didn't enable the warning, ah, that's another problem. Thanks for the illustration code. I'm feeling like I'm enlightened :)

Comment: You should always use strict; and use warnings; even in 'toy' code. When you fix all errors and warnings your code will be better.

Comment: @Mike: this is not the first time you've been counselled to always use strict and warnings. Please start heeding this advice; you will be much happier and more productive :)

Comment: @Sorpigal and @Ether, I'll be heeding your advice for future codings. Thanks :)